# Prevent router-outlet default property

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, router-outlet

I Want to enable/disable `router-outlet` dynamically. When `router-outlet` was disabled then, `tab-outlet` handle routing. This is interesting for me that when `isActivate false` then `tab-outlet` work fine! But when `isActivate true` by default and disable manually (click by button) It Dosn't work.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {

  isActivate = true;

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  onDeactive() {
    this.isActivate = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    });
  }

}
```

```
<app-tab-outlet></app-tab-outlet>
 <router-outlet *ngIf="isActivate"></router-outlet>
<button type="button" (click)="onToggle()">Show RouterOutlet</button>
```

See in [Stackbilitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fp15ov?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Can you try with `<ng-container *ngIf="isActivate"><router-outlet></router-outlet></ng-container>`?

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies Yes,It didn't work

Comment: Can I know why would you do that?